# How to force CMake to ignore sytem db.h header file in favour of installed version on Mac?

Tags: c++, macos, cmake, libdbi

I'm trying to port my CMake library to mac. I'm linking berkerly DB so I've installed it using brew and I'm able to find the appropriate paths (library, include etc) in cmake. They are

```
    Berkerly
        BERKELY_STATIC_LIBRARY              /usr/local/lib/libdb.a
        BERKELY_lIBRARY                     /usr/local/lib/libdb.dylib
        BERKELY_INCLUDE_DIR                 /usr/local/include
```

However, my library doesn't compile because the dependency I am compiling includes db.h

```
#include <db.h>
```

which also exists at

```
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX10.15.sdk/usr/include/db.h
```

and is being used in preference to the one at `/usr/local/include`. Is it be possible to force CMake to use the `db.h` from `/usr/local/include` instead of the other one?

Comment: How are you finding the header? I think you need to show a minimal CMakeLists.txt

Comment: CLion allows you to control and click into a include file to see its source.